# how to allow only keyboard characters while submitting a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

how to validate the text field while submitting the form using jquery to display an alert message if the text field contains other than keyboard special characters like ascii characters form 127-255 and iso-8859-1 caharacters

**Sample Code :**

**Javascript Code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {           
        $('#send').click(function()
        {
            var firstname=$('#firstname').val();
            var pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/']+$";
            if((!firstname.match(pattern)))
            {
                alert('your input contained not supported characters');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Html Code :**

```
<form id="ajax_form" action="ajaxoutput.php">
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" /><br>
<input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="LastName" /><br>
<input type="file" name="image"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="send" /> <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>
```

Comment: yes i use that one, but it allow only alphanumeric characters, how to allow keyboard symbols also

Comment: One way would be to add manually each one of them. I am pretty someone already did it, so you can try to google and find an already existing RegEx.

Comment: I think "only keyboard character" is imprecise, but I assume you want to say only european (or maybe american) keyboard characters

Comment: My keyboard has all of `áěěíóúůýčďňřšťž`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string as `.match()` argument whilke it need a regular expression.

To create a regexp, you can do this :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/']+$");
```

or

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/']+$/;
```

Then match will work!

Since you use a lot of special character, you'll probly need to escape some of them aswell (with `\`).

Comment: i have tried ur code, it is worked fine, but how to allow special carachters like []\ in the above code

Comment: if i am not misstaken, you need to escape them like that : `\\ \[ \]`

Comment: The `.` must be escaped too and probly the *, the +, the $ and the ^. Well better try it and check if you need to escape them